# Organizing views in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have about 20 controllers in my application, and a folder for each of them inside the view folder. So the architecture is pretty clean, but I have to add other views like pagination, filters etc.

So the view folder contains ~50 sub-folders, half of them are for controllers, half for some other things. Is there a way to organize this mess? I mean, is there some good practice to do this?

Comment: You could extract common partials to a subpath if there are any. Also, try to make your views as modular as possible and reuse them more.

Comment: Something like pagination should probably be one file containing what is needed to work for all views and then included in your base or layout file towards the start of the chain. This is how its done with knp pagination bundle at least. Then you just pass the variables from each controller.

Comment: I agree with @Doug. I have a common folder named Blocks (in view) where there are all the files that can be included anywhere. The use is pretty simple, when I need one of this block (using twig) I only need to include it extending the base layout and overriding the relative block to add what I need where I want (page_content or page_header for instance). You need only to create some blocks inside your base layout that will provide in the future the places needed by the blocks you'll create.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should divide your application into more bundles.